# Nothing appear in HTML after referencing to external js script

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I am trying to draw a ball in my html using javascript. The javascript is referenced by the HTML file since it is an external script. However, I only get a blank page in return. Can someone help please? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width,initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type = "text/javascript" src="projectscripts.js"></script>
    </head>   
    <body onload="ball.draw()">
<canvas id="canvas" width = "3000" height = "3000"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

In my javascript file:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var raf;

var ball = {
  x: 600,
  y: 300,
  radius: 25,
  color: 'blue',
  draw: function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fill();
  }
};
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Move the `<script type = "text/javascript" src="projectscripts.js"></script>` just before `</body>`.

The error comes, because the script is executed before the body is rendered, and because of that the variable `canvas` is `null` and everything that is using it "blows".

I recommend to always have the devtools open, so you can debug and see errors.